# python template with default value

Tags: python, python-2.7

In python I can use a template with

```
from string import Template
templ = Template('hello ${name}')
print templ.substitute(name='world')
```

how can I define a default value in the template?
And call the template without any value.

```
print templ.substitute()
```

Edit

And when I call without parameters get the default value, example

```
 print templ.substitute()
 >> hello name
```

Comment: Sorry, i didnt understand the question at hand so i deleted my answer. I thought the question was related to creating default values for a class.

Comment: `substitute` takes a mapping and kwargs, and the kwargs override the mapping ... which makes the mapping argument a natural way to pass defaults:  `defaults = { "foo": "bar" }; Template("hello ${foo}").substitute(defaults, foo="baz")`

Comment: @MatthewStory I think that's the best answer here. I would encourage you to write it up as such.

Comment: @AdamSmith done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Template.substitute` method takes a [`mapping` argument in addition to keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string.Template.substitute). The keyword arguments override the arguments provided by the `mapping` positional argument, which makes `mapping` a natural way to implement defaults without needing to subclass:

```
from string import Template
defaults = { "name": "default" }
templ = Template('hello ${name}')
print templ.substitute(defaults)               # prints hello default
print templ.substitute(defaults, name="world") # prints hello world
```

This will also work for `safe_substitute`:

```
print templ.safe_substitute()                       # prints hello ${name}
print templ.safe_substitute(defaults)               # prints hello default
print templ.safe_substitute(defaults, name="world") # prints hello world
```

If you are absolutely insistent on passing no arguments to `substitute` you could subclass Template:

```
class DefaultTemplate(Template):
    def __init__(self, template, default):
        self.default = default
        super(DefaultTemplate, self).__init__(template)

    def mapping(self, mapping):
        default_mapping = self.default.copy()
        default_mapping.update(mapping)
        return default_mapping

    def substitute(self, mapping=None, **kws):
        return super(DefaultTemplate, self).substitute(self.mapping(mapping or {}), **kws)

    def substitute(self, mapping=None, **kws):
        return super(DefaultTemplate, self).safe_substitute(self.mapping(mapping or {}), **kws)
```

And then use it like this:

```
DefaultTemplate({ "name": "default" }).substitute()
```

Although I find this to be less explicit and less readable than just passing a `mapping` with defaults to `substitute`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your proxy to Template class and store substitutes there.

```
from string import Template
from copy import copy


class TemplateWithDefaults(Template):

    def __init__(self, template, **defaults):
        self.defaults = defaults or {}
        super(TemplateWithDefaults, self).__init__(template)

    def build_mapping(self, *args, **kwargs):
        mapping = copy(self.defaults)
        if len(args) == 1:
            mapping.update(args[0])
        mapping.update(kwargs)
        return mapping

    def substitute(*args, **kwargs):
        self, args = args[0], args[1:]
        mapping = self.build_mapping(*args, **kwargs)
        return super(TemplateWithDefaults, self).substitute(mapping, **kwargs)

    def safe_substitute(*args, **kwargs):
        self, args = args[0], args[1:]
        mapping = self.build_mapping(*args, **kwargs)
        return super(TemplateWithDefaults, self).safe_substitute(mapping, **kwargs)

template = TemplateWithDefaults("$wow", wow=1)

print template.substitute() # outputs 1
print template.substitute(wow=2) # outputs 2
print template.substitute({"wow": 2}) # outputs 2
print template.substitute() # outputs 1 (means no side effects)
```

UPD: edited code to handle dict as first argument. Original api compatibility.

Comment: This isn't quite right. `substitute` takes a `mapping` *and* kwargs ... and the kwargs override the mapping. `Template("${foo}").substitute({ "foo": "bar" }, foo="baz")` <- returns "baz". Based on how you're updating kwargs, your defaults will override a passed mapping. e.g. `template.substitute({ "wow": 2})` would output `1` not `2`. So really you want to do: `mapping = copy(self.defaults); mapping.update(args[0] if args or {}); super(...).substitute(mapping, **kwargs)`

Comment: It was really hard to match signatures of oldschool class, especially when self word is omitted. I don't see incompatibilities in that behaviour and seriously doubt that Template api will ever dramatically change. Seems good enough.

Comment: The `self, args = args[0], args[1:]` is not really something you see in python. `def substitute(self, *args, **kwargs):` is far more common. Beyond that you know you only have 1 positional argument, so there's no need for variable args (which complicates `build_mapping`). I've read and know the actual implementation of `string.Template` uses a similar Idiom to the one you are using here, but I would offer them the same criticism to them.

Answer (score 0):

If the default value is the variable name (like in the question), the missing data could be added automatically:

```
class MyTemplate(Template):
    def substitute(self, *args, **kwds):
        try:
            return super().substitute(*args, **kwds)
        except KeyError as err:
            key = str(err.args[0])
            kwds[key] = key 
            return self.substitute(*args, **kwds)
```

Comment: mapping is not a required arg, so your signature is wrong. Also replacing the variable name with the variable name was not the request of the OP.

Comment: @MatthewStory It is documented that way, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Template.substitute  However it appears the mappings optional indeed, I will edit my answer.

Comment: @MatthewStory In the example added to the question, the default for `${name}` when `name` is not provided is `"name"`.